# From local tiles to WMS via Mapproxy

Tags: wms, tiles, tilecache, mapproxy

I have any local tiles (seed via Mapproxy) of any local area. May I configure mapproxy that I can use a local tile directory on my computer as a source  and get the output then WMS ?
I've already configured mapproxy.yaml which has this lines:
services:

```
demo:
  wms:
    srs: ['EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3395']
    # image_formats: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
    md:
      # metadata used in capabilities documents
      title: MapProxy WMS Proxy
      abstract: This is the fantastic MapProxy.
      online_resource: http://mapproxy.org/
      contact:
        person: Your Name Here
        position: Technical Director
        organization: 
        address: Fakestreet 123
        city: Somewhere
        postcode: 12345
        country: Germany
        phone: +49(0)000-000000-0
        fax: +49(0)000-000000-0
        email: info@omniscale.de
      access_constraints:
        This service is intended for private and evaluation use only.
        The data is licensed as Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 2.0
        (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/)
      fees: 'None'

layers:
  - name: Testing tiles
    title: Testing tiles
    sources: [osm_cached]
caches:
  osm_cached:
    grids: [gmaps_grid]
    sources: []
    cache:
     type: file
     directory_layout: tms

grids:
  gmaps_grid:
    tile_size: [256, 256]
    srs: EPSG:3857
    origin: nw
```

But cannot see the results, just empty page whout scrolling
Please explain should I use cache->directory_layoutORdirectory? If so how does it look?

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly MapProxy documentation `sources` parameter of `caches` section is mandatory, but as I can see you use empty list. You should point source of your cache. If you are planning to use your source only during the seeding process - option [seed_only](http://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/sources.html#wms-seed-only) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanx, Denis I'll check your suggestions.